# Wake on Lan Dual boot Windows 10 + ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, wakeonlan

Unfortunately I can not get wake on lan working with ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10.
If I shutdown from ubuntu wol works perfectly. However, if I shutdown in Windows wake on lan does not work. I have enabled wake on lan on windows 10.
Windows and Ubuntu are on different disks should that matter.

Any clue on how to solve this problem?